# Migrating from basemap to cartopy - coordinates offset?

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

I was happy with basemap showing some points of interest I have visited, but since basemap is dead, I am moving over to cartopy.
So far so good, I have transferred all the map features (country borders, etc.) without major problems, but I have noticed my points of interest are shifted a bit to North-East in cartopy.

Minimal example from the old basemap (showing two points of interest on the Germany-Czech border):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map = Basemap(projection='merc', epsg='3395',
          llcrnrlon = 11.5, urcrnrlon = 12.5,
          llcrnrlat = 50, urcrnrlat = 50.7,
          resolution = 'f')

map.fillcontinents(color='Bisque',lake_color='LightSkyBlue')
map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.2)

lats = [50.3182289, 50.2523744]
lons = [12.1010486, 12.0906336]

x, y = map(lons, lats)

map.plot(x, y, marker = '.', markersize=1, mfc = 'red', mew = 1, mec = 'red', ls = 'None')

plt.savefig('example-basemap.png', dpi=200, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

And the same example from cartopy - both points are slightly shifted to North-East as can be verified also e.g. via google maps:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())

ax.set_extent([11.5, 12.5, 50, 50.7])

ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND.with_scale('10m'), color='Bisque')
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES.with_scale('10m'), alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS.with_scale('10m'), linewidth=0.2)

lats = [50.3182289, 50.2523744]
lons = [12.1010486, 12.0906336]

ax.plot(lons, lats, transform=ccrs.Geodetic(),
    marker = '.', markersize=1, mfc = 'red', mew = 1, mec = 'red', ls = 'None')

plt.savefig('cartopy.png', dpi=200, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Any idea how to get cartopy plot the points on expected coordinates? Tried cartopy 0.18 and 0.20 with the same result.

Comment: How much the discrepancies are, when you compare with G maps? G maps use `Web Mercator` which is an approx. of Mercator.

Comment: It is hard to gauge, given the crude display of the country border, but I would say about 1-2km.If you could run the examples, it would produce png files, where it would be nicely visible.

Comment: you may report the problem/bug to the Cartopy development team on Github.

Comment: Hi @Jana, did you solve this problem?